# Servlet filter не дает подгрузить ссылку на js библиотеку в jsp файле

Tags: java, servlet

У меня в фильтре открыт доступ на index.jsp. index загружается но вот ссылки в индексе на файлы css и js не проходят т.к. без фильтра все работает гуд.
Почему так? Надо еще как-то окрыть доступ на папку с js и css?

Фильтр

```
  if (path.equals("/") || path.equals("/index.jsp")){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp");
            servletRequest.setAttribute("message", "Добро пожаловать");
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
```

index

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tabulator/tabulator.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда идет отрисовка jsp и встречается строка с подключаемым js,css. Они подгружаются на страницу отдельным запросом, соответственно в ваш фильтр в if попадает примерно следующее:

```
path="/tabulator/tabulator.js"
```

Чтобы фильтр пропускал подобные файлы необходимо добавить условие, примерно так

```
if (path.matches(".*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)") {
....
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня так и не получилось воспользоваться вашим советом. Проблема заключалась в том что в фильтре не выполнялось условие filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);